# Does creating a FK automatically index the column?

Tags: sql, mysql

I am using mySQL 5.1 and am wondering, is it necessary to add CREATE INDEX syntax on a column after you have defined it in a FK relationship. Common sense tells me that if a column is a key (foreign or otherwise), then it needs to be indexed - but you never know ...

Do I have to EXPLICITLY create an index on my FK - or does creating an FK implicitly creates an index on the column ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quoting this page of the MySQL manual : [13.6.4.4. FOREIGN KEY Constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) :

> InnoDB requires indexes on foreign
>   keys and referenced keys so that
>   foreign key checks can be fast and not
>   require a table scan.  
> In the
>   referencing table, there must be an
>   index where the foreign key columns
>   are listed as the first columns in the
>   same order.  
> **Such an index is
>   created on the referencing table
>   automatically if it does not exist.**

Comment: MySQL is unusual in this regard, although I wish other products would do the same.

Comment: +1 One interesting effect is that on MyISAM (which doesn't support foreign keys), declaring a foreign key still creates an index.

Comment: @Alex: Right, a foreign key does not have to be unique.  If it did, you could never have a many-to-one relationship.